# Add additional fields in angular-nvd3 tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm creating a scatter chart using angular-nvd3 (e.g. http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/scatterChart). I can create a custom tooltip using the below function

```
tooltip: {
  contentGenerator: function(d) { return '<h3>HELLO WORLD</h3>'; }
}
```

My requirement however is more basic and to add a couple of additional fields (if not null) in the default tooltip generated by nvd3.

Is it possible to map the textvalue property in the graph's data object to the the default nvd3 toolip?

```
{
x: 1460199045.987,
y: 0,
textvalue: "117 test comment"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved by copying the contentGenerator function from the nvd3 source code (which creates a html table) and then modifying it according to my requirements. Not the cleanest solution but it works.

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/tooltip.js